# Open Direct Project or Directory when user enter Localhost

Tags: php, browser, wampserver

I want, whenever I type localhost in my browser it should open direct Project orDirectory for Example

My directory name is **RFI_tages/index.php**

when I enter localhost in the browser it should open **localhost/RFI_tags/index.php**

I don't want to open localhost index page where all project exists

Comment: Create a [Virtual Host as suggested here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,146746) then you can access your site using a domain name like `rfitags` for example

Comment: The WAMPServer homepage cna be very useful at time, best to leave it where it is

Comment: Thanku so much brother i got solution